# How to convert size_t to char* in kernel C?

Tags: c, kernel, kernel-module

I use a `size_t` variable in my kernel module. when I want to write it to a file it must be cast to `char*` according to `vfs_write` signature:

```
extern ssize_t vfs_write(struct file *, const char __user *, size_t, loff_t *);
```

I use this function that uses `vfs_write` (I found it on internet):

```
int file_write(struct file *file, unsigned long long offset, unsigned 
char *data, unsigned int size) 
{
    mm_segment_t oldfs;
    int ret;

    oldfs = get_fs();
    set_fs(get_ds());

    ret = vfs_write(file, data, size, &offset);

    set_fs(oldfs);
    return ret;
}
```

the `nbytes` variable is `size_t` I try `(char *)` cast for convert `nbytes` to `char*` but the kernel immediately crashes. here is my code.

```
index_filename = "/home/rocket/Desktop/index_pool";
index_file = file_open(index_filename,O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0644);
if(index_file == NULL)
    printk(KERN_ALERT "index_file open error !!.\n");
else{
    // file_write(index_file, 0, nbytes, nbytes); => this crashs also
    file_write(index_file, 0, (char*) nbytes, 100);
    file_close(index_file);
}
```

Is there a way to safely convert `size_t` type to `char *` one in Kernel ?

Comment: A `size_t` is far less than 100 bytes big.

Comment: @tkausl what should I write instead of it ? `sizeof (char*)nbytes` ? or something else ? it seems doesn't work

Comment: What you need is a *pointer* to the variable `nbytes`. You can get that with the address-of operator `&`. As in `&nbytes`. And the size of `nbytes` is `sizeof nbytes`, which is much less than `100`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it would crash - you're trying to write 100 bytes of whatever memory location `nbytes` is pointing at. Which because it isn't a pointer is extremely unlikely to be a valid area of memory. And even if it was, it might not be 100 bytes in size.

What you want to be passing instead to `vfs_write` is a pointer to `nbytes`. And the size of that would be `sizeof(nbytes)`. So you'd call your wrapper function like this

```
file_write(index_file, 0, (char*) &nbytes, sizeof(nbytes));
```

That will write out the how ever many bytes that a `size_t` is at the memory location of `nbytes`

If you want to write out the value of `nbytes`, which is different to what you appear to be asking in the question, you need to store it in a string and pass that to your function like this:

```
char temp_string[20];
sprintf(temp_string,"%zu",nbytes);
file_write(index_file, 0, temp_string, strlen(temp_string));
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `(unsigned char *)` instead of `(char *)`?

Comment: thanks it now doesn't crash. but what is write to file is strange characters like `????`, the `nbytes` is 200 but it convert to strange characters.

Comment: Ah, that is subtly different to what you asked. You need to use `sprintf` to store the value of `nbytes` in a string and send that to the function. I'll update my answer with how to do that.

Comment: @MichaelWalz maybe? the OP's function and `vfs_write` conflict in whether the `char *` should be signed or not.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to safely convert size_t type to char * one in Kernel ?

yes there is.
you should use `sprintf` function in `linux/kernel.h` library

so you should do something like this:

```
sprintf(destination_char_star, "%zu", your_s_size_var);
```

be carefull you should allocate memory to char star if needed.